# Automatically freeing memory when using C-allocated ctypes structures in Python

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a C library and I am creating a Python wrapper using `ctypes`. I have defined subclasses of `ctypes.Structure` for all of the C structures that are used by the library, and I have also created several Python classes that wrap these C structures using Python-friendly interfaces. (So basically each Python structure contains a `ctypes.Structure` subclass as a member and then has a bunch of methods that operate on the Structure.) There is quite a bit of (necessary) cyclicity in the structures, and the structures are allocated on the C side. (I know this makes things more difficult.) I want to have the memory for the corresponding C structures be freed when the Python objects are garbage-collected (transparently to the client of my wrapper library); I have functions to deallocate the memory. My initial approach was to use the `__del__` method for this purpose, but defining `__del__` interferes with garbage collection since there are cyclic references in the structures. Is there another common way to manage this without requiring the client of my wrapper to explicitly free the structures?

Comment: It appears perhaps that there isn't a cyclicity in the `ctypes.Structure` subclasses (`ctypes.POINTER` doesn't induce a reference?) so the `__del__` method there is an option...still interested to hear if there is a better way though.

Comment: Why wrap the `Structure` instead of adding the interface directly?

Comment: As to `POINTER` instances created from fields, they can create a cycle if you store a reference back to the `Structure` instance, which you should avoid if you use `__del__`.

Comment: I could certainly add the interface to the `Structure` as well...I don't think it makes a difference to this question though.

Comment: As long as you don't intentionally create a cycle, using `__del__` should be fine. Also, if your `Structure` instance is temporary you can also use the context manager protocol `__enter__` and `__exit__` in a `with` statement.